# Iterate over Array of images

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I've created an array and pushed 30 Images into it, and implemented the keyPressed() function to change the image drawn randomly from the array but when I test it, it just changes the image one time only without looping over the array.

here is my example code simulates my problem

```
function keyPressed() {
    loop();
    //press left arrow to change pic
    if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){
        for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
            image(imgs[i], 0 ,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean the `image()` function draws an image, and the loop is supposed to create an animation, you will need a timer instead of the loop. Nothing appears on the screen until your JS code returns, that's why you will see the last frame only.

Comment: can you provide me with an example code to understand your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyPressed()` function is only called at the moment when you press down the key. It is not called repeatedly while you hold it down.

One solution is to use the built-in boolean variable `keyIsPressed`, which is true when any key is pressed. You might do something like this:

```
let img_number = 0;

function setup() {
  //whatever is in your setup
}

function draw() {
  if (keyIsPressed) {
    if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
      img_number = (img_number + 1) % imgs.length;
    }
  }
  image(imgs[img_number];
}
```

If you're using `noLoop()`, I recommend finding an alternative because p5.js takes inputs like this:

1. Run the `setup()` block
2. Run the `draw()` block
3. Listen for input (check where the cursor is, whether the mouse was clicked, what keys were pressed, etc.)
4. Run the appropriate commands (`keyPressed()`, `mouseClicked()`, etc.)
5. Repeat 2-4 until `noLoop()` is called

So when you call `noLoop()`, the computer is no longer listening for your input, and is simply ignoring you.